# Is mdadm fail a definitive status?

Tags: hard-disk, mdadm, software-raid

Today, `mdadm` sent me message via `mail`, that one drive in one RAID1 array has fail status.

I have no problem with replacing the drive as I have a few spare ones.

I don't fully understand how `mdadm` evaluated the drive as failed, so I have a question for you.

Is `mdadm` fail a definitive status or can I somehow try to resurrect the drive?

I can still access the drive for example with `gdisk`, so the drive is not technically dead (yet), that's why I'm asking.

Details:

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md1
```

outputs:

```
/dev/md1:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sun Mar 26 17:25:30 2017
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 976630464 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 976630464 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Mon Oct  2 07:31:25 2017
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : backup-server:1  (local to host backup-server)
           UUID : 319334f9:76d6fccf:d61307bd:2427b6ba
         Events : 13023

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       49        0      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       -       0        0        1      removed

       1       8       65        -      faulty   /dev/sde1
```

and

```
hdparm -I /dev/sde
```

outputs:

```
/dev/sde:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       WDC WD1002F9YZ-09H1JL1
        Serial Number:      WD-WMC5K0D33MEU
        Firmware Revision:  01.01M03
        Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
        Supported: 8 7 6 5
        Likely used: 8
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16383
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
        LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
        LBA48  user addressable sectors:  1953525168
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
        Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:      953869 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:     1000204 MBytes (1000 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
        Form Factor: 3.5 inch
        Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 7200
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
        Queue depth: 32
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, with device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 0
        Advanced power management level: 128
        DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    SMART feature set
                Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    NOP cmd
           *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Advanced Power Management feature set
                Power-Up In Standby feature set
           *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
           *    48-bit Address feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
           *    SMART error logging
           *    SMART self-test
           *    General Purpose Logging feature set
           *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
           *    64-bit World wide name
           *    IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
           *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
           *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
           *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
                unknown 119[7]
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
           *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
           *    Phy event counters
           *    Idle-Unload when NCQ is active
           *    NCQ priority information
           *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
           *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
           *    Software settings preservation
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
           *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
           *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
           *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
                unknown 206[7]
                unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
                unknown 206[13] (vendor specific)
           *    DOWNLOAD MICROCODE DMA command
           *    WRITE BUFFER DMA command
           *    READ BUFFER DMA command
Security:
        Master password revision code = 65534
                supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
        not     frozen
        not     expired: security count
                supported: enhanced erase
        112min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 112min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 50014ee05950af82
        NAA             : 5
        IEEE OUI        : 0014ee
        Unique ID       : 05950af82
Checksum: correct
```

and

```
smartctl -a /dev/sde
```

outputs:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.9.0-3-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Se
Device Model:     WDC WD1002F9YZ-09H1JL1
Serial Number:    WD-WMC5K0D33MEU
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 05950af82
Firmware Version: 01.01M03
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Oct  2 07:41:14 2017 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (10560) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 118) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x30bd) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   174   171   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       2291
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       202
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       5402
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       202
 16 Unknown_Attribute       0x0022   255   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       8668797885185
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       65
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       136
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   106   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       37
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       20
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not final; you can try restoring a device with `--re-add`. There’s even a variant which will automatically re-add all failed devices:

```
mdadm --re-add /dev/md1 faulty
```

The kernel logs should tell you why the drive was marked as failed. I suspect the UDMA CRC errors given the SMART status. You can also view the extended error logs on the drive using

```
smartctl -x /dev/sde
```

These should indicate the nature of the error; for example

```
Error 10 [9] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 31192 hours (1299 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 73 30 a5 58 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x7330a558 = 1932567896

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 05 00 00 e0 00 00 73 30 a1 00 40 08 13d+02:07:12.334  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 d8 00 00 03 d3 aa c0 40 08 13d+02:07:12.334  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 05 00 00 d0 00 00 73 30 9c 00 40 08 13d+02:07:12.327  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 c8 00 00 03 d3 a9 90 40 08 13d+02:07:12.327  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 05 00 00 c0 00 00 73 30 97 00 40 08 13d+02:07:12.321  READ FPDMA QUEUED
```

(from one of my SMART test drives).

Answer (score 0):

The drive has been probably `fail`ed by mdadm because of a Uncorrectable Read Error (UCE). You could search about that in the kernel logs (try grepping about `sde`).

That said, this is not a definitive status: the error could have been caused by many transient factors, including a High Fly Write, or a bad cable.

Your best bet is to use the hard drive manufacturer tools to analyze and repair it; however, for recent HDDs, you can try these steps, which I used successfully in the past years, and have restored some drives which are still in production with 50k+ hours:

DISCLAIMER: YOU WILL LOSE ALL DATA ON THE /dev/sde DRIVE IF YOU USE THESE COMMANDS!!!

1. Launch a SMART long test: `smartctl -t long /dev/sde`
2. Clear all the drive with zeros: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde` (this is what many HDD manufacturer tools actually do in their recovery routines)
3. Re-partition your drive
4. Re-add the drive to the array

Ideally, the [1] point should fail at some sector, and the [2] point should help the HDD logic to (1) mark the "broken" sector as definitively broken, and find a substitute one for it or (2) fully recover the sector.

Comment: Given that the drive is (was) in a RAID array, scrubbing it would be more appropriate than zero-ing it... In any case since there are no uncorrectable sectors listed in the SMART data, there probably isn’t any sector needing recovery.

Comment: Maybe scrubbing would be better.. but, thinking about the question again, we definitely need the kernel logs to proceed with more steps here. And, if nothing appears in the kernel logs about sde, I would definitely disconnect the drive from the array and treat it as "not trusted anymore" until the drive is able to perform
- full SMART long test
- zerofill
- mdadm re-add
correctly without problems